# Configure Controlm jobs through Backend?

Tags: shell, control-m

We have number of jobs configured in Controlm and now we got new environment  to configure same set of jobs,
Is there any way to create controlm jobs from backend server by writing shell or any scripts? 
Any other possibilities to avoid spending time in creating same jobs again and again for each environment??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Control-M provides the functionality to export/import jobs across environments : https://communities.bmc.com/docs/DOC-50416

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways:

From the Planning domain, load the job folders you want to migrate into a blank workspace.
from the top bar then click Export and save.  This will save a .xml file you can edit using a text editor and then Import Workspace and load - you can import the .xml into the same Control-M if environments are on one CTM EM Server, or a different CTM EM Server.

OR
From the planning Domain, load the job folders you want to migrate, right click on the folder and select Duplicate, then through the GUI update the new folder (If doing this I'd then unload the source folder just to ensure nothing is overwritten there).  You can use the Find & Update option.  This will only work if your environments are on the same CTM EM server.